# BootStrap show element upon collapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am using BootStrap. I have a navbar at the bottom of my page with a phone number. I want that phonenumber to be hidden upon collapse and then show a phone icon instead. Currently I can't get the phone icon to be hidden before collapse. Here is my code:

```
<div class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class ="container">
                <div>
                    <a href = "#" target="_blank" class= "brand pull-left"> <img src="logo.png" alt="#" href="#"> </a>
                </div>

                <div class = "collapse.in navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="bund-navbar-collapse-semi">
                    <a class = "navbar-btn btn-success btn-xl btn pull-right">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" ></span> 
                    </a>

                </div>


                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="bund-navbar-collapse-fuld" >
                    <a class = "navbar-btn btn-success btn-xl btn pull-right">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone "></span> +45 30 30 30 30
                    </a>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Which bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 3

Answer (score 1):

make use of the [responsive-utilitie classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) from Bootstrap.

add the classes

```
hidden-sm
hidden-md
hidden-lg
```

to the button with just the phone icon, see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SEb5d/1/). Never mind that the icon isn't showing properly. I would use [bootply](http://bootply.com) but its down for maintenance.